Как задать имя процесса в BASH при запуске в фоне?
Имеется команда:
{command1 > /dev/null; command2 > /dev/null} &
Она запускает 2 комманды последовательно, проблема в том что не возможно этот процесс найти по названию command1 или command2 тк он отображается без названия команд:
ps aug | grep 10837;
root   10837  0.0  0.0 155152 10088 pts/8    SN   13:29   0:00 -zsh

Можно ли как то задать имя для данного процесса?

Это точно баш? Почему-то ч вижу zsh

Добавьте детали. Какой интерпретатор, какие команды, как вы получили идентификатор процесса 10837.

Из общих соображений, при выполнениии {list}& шелл форкается и порождается сабшелл, который выполняет последовательность команд list. Неудивительно, что вы по номеру процесса наблюдаете zsh. В имени этого сабшелла нет ни command1, ни command2. Пример: { sleep 25; ls >/dev/null; }& ps $!. Результат 19702 pts/2    S      0:00 -bash - интерпретатор форкнулся для выполнения команд в сабшелле

Также учтите, что если command1 и command2 встроенные в shell, то имя процесса и будет имя интерпретатора shell.
